# Does SVN Server and Clients have to be on the same OS type environment?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, centos6

I am thinking about setting up `SVN Server on CentOS` (http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#centos). But I am not sure if the SVN Clients will also have to be on CentOS only? or can be any client such as Windows `Tortoise SVN`?

Thanks a lot.

[Update]
Also, if there is any free Build/Binnary for SVN Server on CentOS? Or do I have to start with the source code and make a build myself?

Comment: No you can use the client on any platform for which the client will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to put a simple comment, but since you asked about building from the source...

Subversion has defined an API that clients can use, and is one of the few version control systems that actually did this too. This means you can use any Subversion client with any server since there is no dependency on a command line client to talk to the server. As of now, you're even free to mix and match versions. A 1.9 version of the server can use any client from 1.1 to 1.9. A 1.1 version of the Subversion server can use any client from 1.1 to 1.9. (This isn't very recommended because you'll lose a lot of the newer features. Normally, you shouldn't use anything less than 1.6 for client or server).

So, if you use a CentOS server, you can use the standard command line Windows client, the TortoiseSVN client, the IDE clients found in Eclipse, VisualStudio, IntelliJ, etc. Mac OS X clients of various sorts, and even Unix and Linux clients of all flavors.

Now, about the server...

I rarely recommend for someone to compile the Subversion source into a server. This is because of the long, long string of dependencies. This is especially true if you plan to use the Apache httpd server as your Subversion server. Apache itself might have to be recompiled with newer versions of various libraries in order to build the modules needed for Subversion. The APR is usually a bear to get right. It's no fun. No fun at all.

However, CentOS should have a Subversion server package that will update the Apache server to work with Subversion. I don't know what version it is, but you might want to look at it.

CollabNet produces a package called [SubversionEdge](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion) that includes an Apache server, a Subversion server, Subversion client, and even ViewVC that acts as a Subversion web client. You install this as a single package, and it replaces the already existing Apache httpd installation. (It doesn't replace it, but it installs a second one. You should make sure the default one doesn't run with this one running).

[Wandisco](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download) makes their own package for CentOS. I haven't tried that one, but there's no reason you shouldn't.

Comment: OK great info.. So is CollabNet build is free? I think I saw a `trial` word somewhere there...

Comment: It's free as in beer. CollabNet, however, will be more than happy to offer you paid support for Subversion. Word of warning: SubversionEdge is Apache `httpd` with Subversion modules needed to run Subversion server. It doesn't come with a neato, cool, GUI to administer it. You administer it by hewing the needed configurations through vim and the command line. Fortunately, there are [good resources](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) to help you get everything setup. If you have any tech experience, you should be fine.

Comment: Ok so I am looking over here:
http://www.collab.net/products/subversion
and it says each product has a cost...

Comment: The _cost_ is the cost for support. There's a big yellow button on the page that says _Download it for Free_.

Comment: Ok.. I thought its Free to Download, but Pay to Use.. Like it would require some activation...